# tooltipShowDelay option in AG grid is not working

Tags: vue.js, tooltip, ag-grid-vue

I am using AG Grid version 26.2 and Vue 2.

What I am trying to do is set the tooltipShowDelay to 0 so the tooltip will render instantaneously.

The very first render takes about ~2 seconds which is the default value and afterwards is instantaneous.

I tried all the posibilites I could think of:

```
<ag-grid-vue :tooltipShowDelay="0"> </ag-grid-vue>
```

OR

```
data() { 
 return {
   tooltipShowDelay: null,
  }
}
created() {
   this.tooltipShowDelay = 0;
}
```

and within the template

```
<ag-grid-vue :tooltipShowDelay="tooltipShowDelay"> </ag-grid-vue>
```

I even set enableBrowserTooltips to false so it will not interfere in anyway with the custom tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have `enableBrowserTooltips` set to `true`, and if so, remove it or set it to `false`. This was the problem I had.

The [docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-options/#miscellaneous) say that:

> `enableBrowserTooltips` (`boolean`): Set to true to use the browser's default tooltip instead of using the grid's Tooltip Component.